# Parameters not being passed from VB8 to .NET asmx Service

Tags: xml, vb6, asmx

I am the unfortunate position of working with some legacy code, so please please, do not critisize the methods I am employing.

I have a VB6 app which passes XML to an asmx service, however when the XML arrives at the service, the parameters of the functions fail to populate.

Has anyone experience this in the past??

I have done all the usual things of checking namespaces, SOAPactions, char sets etc but cannot get this to work

I have tried using Fiddler, but I cannot intercept the traffic and nothing shows up.

Comment: You typoed VB6 in the title